# How can extract Html from a WidgetT (HandlerSite LiteHandler) IO () value in Yesod

Tags: haskell, yesod

Shalom! I have the following code:

```
widget_member :: Html -> MForm LiteHandler (FormResult Member, WidgetT (HandlerSite LiteHandler) IO ())
widget_member = renderDivs input_member

handler_home :: LiteHandler Html
handler_home = do
    (widget, e) <- generateFormPost widget_member
```

Can anyone show how I can extract the Html from `widget` so that handler_home can return it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably don't want to actually extract the `Html`; you probably want to call the `defaultLayout` function. Most examples of using forms take this approach.